# tc server embedded in Spring tools fails to load JNI shared library

Tags: spring, java-native-interface, tcserver, java.library.path

vFabric tc server fails to load my JNI libraries when starting a Spring bean that executes '`System.loadLibrary("...")`'. Indeed, I need to execute some JNI shared library from my Spring beans deployed in vFabric tcServer edition (STS) Spring Tools Suite.

Although I followed the advice in "[Customizing the environment or JVM options for vFabric tc Server (2030216)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2030216)" the error kept poping out: "`nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [my.JniServiceFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no myJNIsharedLib in java.library.path`"

I further discovered error in `wrapper.log` file in the tc server instance `.../bin/winx86_64` directory telling: `Unable to open configuration file. C:\java\SpringTools\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.6.RELEASE\base-instance\bin\winx86_64\wrapper.conf`
and also found errors when executing the wrapper at command line: `wrapper -q ..\..\conf\wrapper.conf`, yielding  `wrapper  | OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)`, which suggested a UAC issue. So I elevated my windows account to Administrator and even turned off UAC... which solved the wrapper.exe error but did not solve the UnsatisfiedLinkError when starting my app in tc server.

I also discovered a '`setenv.bat`' file under the tc server instance directories containing the line '`set JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=`' that invites you to define it, but no effect.
 I also tried setting a global environment variable JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH under my system properties, hence available when starting Spring Tools and then the tc server... no way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution I discovered holds under the Eclipse RUN configurations.

In Eclipse menu run > Run configurations... > VMware vFabric developer Edition > Arguments tab > VM arguments: add to the long listing the extra -Djava.library.path=\java\git\MySharedLibRepo and restart the tc Server... this solves the issue.

Do also ensure under MS-Windows that the target JNI native library that is loaded by `System.loadLibrary("...")` bears the exact basename of the .dll native library (hence without .dll extension).

And indeed no Administrator permission is required. A regular Windows user account is fine.